# Using 'control' css class in Magento for horizontal layout

Tags: css, magento

I have added some radio boxes to the onepage checkout - I am using the following code to use the Magento default CSS styles, this works but as it needs validation too I now need this radio boxes to be display horizontally rather than vertically as the code below does.

Is there another class built into the CSS styles within Magento that can do this?

```
//CSS
<li class="control"><input type="radio" class="radio required-entry" value="1" id="billing:organisation_type" name="billing[organisation_type]"> School</li>
<li class="control"><input type="radio" class="radio required-entry" value="2" id="billing:organisation_type" name="billing[organisation_type]"> Org</li>
<li class="control"><input type="radio" class="radio required-entry" value="3" id="billing:organisation_type" name="billing[organisation_type]"> Org</li>
```

Comment: Why not using display: inline-block; ?

Comment: probably the simplest way of doing it - i was hoping there was a class already setup for this so i didnt need to any extra custom css if possible